# Should Helper methods for cucumber steps definitions be tested?

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java

I am using cucumber for integration testing. The steps definitions use some helper methods so that I don't have to replicate common functions in all the tests. The structure is the following-

```
+---.idea
+---main
|   +---java
|   +---resources
\---test
|   +---java
|   |   \---stepdefs
|   |   |   |---ServiceHooks.java
|   |   |   |---StepDefinitions.java
|   |   |---TestRunner.java
|   |   \---stepdefsHelpers
|   |   |   |---ClientHelper
|   \---resources
|       \---features
|           |---LoginProfile.feature
|           |---UpdateProfile.feature
|---pom.xml
|---testng.xml
```

My question is: **shouldn't I create UT in order to test stepdefsHelpers?** Cause I don't want that somebody messes up the Helpers and my tests become brittle.

Comment: Most definately u need to have unit test for helper methods. Most probably need some mocking api too.

Answer (score 1):

There comes a point with any sort of testing where you have to balance the cost of testing vs the benefits. My experience of Cucumber (10 years approx) suggests that testing helper methods is one of the places where the cost outweighs the benefits.

Helper method code tends to be very fluid, it changes frequently as you learn more about the application and gain capability to test new behaviour which is building on existing behaviour. Such code requires a high level of attention, constant refactoring, and a great deal of discipline in both making the code self explanatory and controlling the size and structure of the API which the helper methods provide. These things are more important than adding unit tests.

Overall I think unit testing is here is likely to be counter-productive.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the second part makes me think that I really need unit tests because in a context where devs of different levels touch the code, attention and constant refactoring is not granted.

Comment: Unit tests for helper methods are likely to lock the API of those methods. These methods need to rapidly evolve as you learn more about your domain, and you need to keep the API size as small as you can. This is a difficult balance to maintain, and personally I think pairing, refactoring and a rigorous review process are far better tools for keeping this particular sort of code in good shape than unit tests. The danger of unit tests here is that they lock the API and increase the cost of change to much. Anyhow just my opinion. Good luck ...

Comment: The devs that touch the code should also make sure the tests keep working. If the interface of the application changes, this means updating the helper methods. The upside of using helper methods, is only having to update those if only the implementation changes, but the behvaiour does not. If the behaviour of the system changes, this means updating description of this behaviour (feature files and probably underlying step definitions and helper methods). Just like they would need to update unit tests and integration tests when making changes to the system.